# How to fix that terminal can't input anything when other shell 'exit'?

Tags: command-line

I found that when I open two terminal and exit any one, it will cause the other can't input any character.

I found that I can use alt+tab change the focus to other program and change back can temporarily back the normal state , but every time when I exit terminal will cause this problem again.

How to fix it?

Comment: Exactly which virtual terminal you use? Gnome terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea on the actual answer, but as a workaround, can you open more than one tab in your terminal program and try that instead of separate terminal windows?  It won't look the way you want it to, but it should provide the same functionality.

I use konsole on kubuntu (kde) and it supports multiple tabs.  I'm sure there is a similar program for your environment.

Also, if you open your second terminal from within your first terminal - from the command line, you may see some error messages there (in the original terminal) when you close the new terminal that may provide clues as to what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I open several tabs on a terminal, not many separate terminals.I open tabs by ctrl+alt+t. I will edit the original post to make it more clearly. What to do next? Thank you~

Comment: Try my second suggestion of opening a second separate terminal from within the first one and see what messages it generates when you close it.  You can also try dmesg to see if anything got written to your system log, but that's not as likely to help.  If anything did get written, it will be at the end, so you don't have to worry about all the rest that will scroll off the screen.  You can also try a different terminal program to see if the problem is just the original program or something more systemic.

Comment: As a variation on my last suggestion, open one terminal window with only one tab.  Use it to open another terminal window with two tabs and recreate your problem.  After you close one or both of the tabs in the second terminal window, see what shows up in the original terminal window.  For completeness, please add the name and version of the terminal program you are using.

Comment: If switching focus to another window and back fixes it - temporarily, it sounds like it may be an input focus problem.  The system is listening to you, but not sending your keypresses to the correct window.  If you have a task manager running in your taskbar, does it indicate that your terminal window is the one that has the focus?  Does clicking/double clicking/right clicking on the terminal window do anything?  If it's just a focus problem, that should get the focus back.  Also please note what desktop environment you are using (gnome?) just to be sure we're talking about the same thing.